# CircleCI: A job that requires a human to start

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm iterating on adding database migrations to a project.  For the first step, I've made a repository that runs migrations.  Now I need to make it so these migrations run against the stage/prod environment.  *I do not want this to happen on every commit.*  Does circle ci provide a way to have a button that I can click on to run a job?

I think ideally I'd have 2 buttons.  One for running migrations on stage, one for running them on prod.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual approval process for workflows.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#holding-a-workflow-for-a-manual-approval

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-test-and-approval-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test1:
          requires:
            - build
      - test2:
          requires:
            - test1
      - hold:
          type: approval
          requires:
           - test2
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - hold
```

It's pretty limited.  You can't use it to start a build.